# Too much recursion (Jquery-tools) or Maximum Call Stack size exceeded

Tags: jquery, jquery-tools

I have the following scenario: I'm using `jquerytools` (newest version, 1.2.6).

This is the `<script>`:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.6/full/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>
```

You might try it, the link works properly.

Then, this is my `HTML`:

```
<div class="images">
    <div style="background: url('basic/start/start_banner_schreib.jpg') no-repeat scroll center -5px transparent; display: none;"><a class="directLink" href="Schreibgeraete-oxid/"><img alt="" src="out/basic/start/spacer.gif" /></a></div>
    <!-- technik -->
    <div style="background: url('basic/start/start_banner_technik.jpg') no-repeat scroll center -5px transparent; display: none;"><a class="directLink" href="Technik/"><img alt="" src="out/basic/start/spacer.gif" /></a></div>
    <!-- Büro & Co -->
    <div style="background: url('basic/start/start_banner_buero_co.jpg') no-repeat scroll center -5px transparent; display: none;"><a class="directLink" href="Buero-Co/"><img alt="" src="out/basic/start/spacer.gif" /></a></div>
    <!-- Zuhause -->
    <div style="background: url('basic/start/start_banner_zuhause.jpg') no-repeat scroll center -5px transparent; display: none;"><a class="directLink" href="Zuhause/"><img alt="" src="out/basic/start/spacer.gif" /></a></div>
</div>
```

Here I have a container, which shall hold the slideshow:

```
<div class="slidetabs">&nbsp;</div>
```

Now least but not least, the function-call at the very end of my site:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
    $(function () {

        $(".slidetabs").tabs(".images > div", {
            effect: 'fade',
            fadeOutSpeed: "slow",
            rotate: true

        }).slideshow({autoplay: true, interval: 4500});

    });
</script>
```

Since the slideshow-plugin is included, I'm using that. I did exactly the same as shown on the [example-page](http://jquerytools.github.io/documentation/tabs/slideshow.html).

However, in **Firefox**, the console throws:

> too much recursion
>
> ...slice:function(){return this.pushStack(F.apply(this,arguments),"slice",F.call(ar...

while in **Chrome** this error occurs:

> Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

I don't include the libs twice (or more often).

Here is a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d0ee36nd/5/) of it.

Comment: Please consider adding an example in a form of Code Snippet, alternatively you might create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: Create a demo that replicates problem

Comment: added a fiddle with the problem

Comment: Well... i can't add the CDN link for this via https... and with just using http it isn't working